# What does the power set mean in the construction of Von Neumann universe?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, foundations

I'm recently learning mathematical logic and axiomatic set theory. I'm using [GTM53](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eshmuel/lg-readings/Manin,%20Logic%20for%20Mathematicians.pdf) as the textbook for mathematical logic. In page 65 of GTM53, when explaining Skolem's paradox, there's a specific notification of power set that the meaning of the power set of a set should be determined by the model we choose, because the axiom of powers only states that: $$\forall x \exists y \forall z\left[\forall u(u \in z \to u \in x) \leftrightarrow z \in y\right],$$
and since the universal quantifier $\forall z$ ranges over the model, this sentence actually means that every set **in the model** which is the subset of $x$ belongs to $y$ (the power set of $x$). This indicates that if the model is "small", then the power set would also be small, and hence there exists a countable model that the power set of a countable set is also countable (in the viewpoint of meta-theory), which explains Skolem's paradox.

People say [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe#Applications_of_V_as_models_for_set_theories) is a model of ZFC. However, in the counstruction of Von Neumann universe, we actually used power set symbol ($V_{\beta+1} = \mathcal P(V_\beta)$). If we must first determine a model to determine what the power symbol means? How can we say Von Neumann universe is model of ZFC as it uses a symbol that has not been defined?

Comment: Von Neumann universe is a way to describe the hierarchy of the set-theoretic universe *internally*, but what the resolution of Skolem paradox pointed out is choosing the model *externally*.

Comment: Who says the von Neumann universe is a model of ZFC, and in what context?  I suspect you are misunderstanding what they are actually trying to say.

Comment: @HanulJeon What does "internally" mean here? Does that mean we need to specify a model of ZFC beforehand to construct Von Neumann universe? Or equavalently does that mean the actual meaning of Von Neumann universe varies according to our selection of "a latent model"?

Comment: @EricWofsey In the WikiPedia page I linked to in the question, there's a section called "Applications of V as models for set theories", and it says "If κ is an inaccessible cardinal, then Vκ is a model of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (ZFC) itself"

Comment: @EricWofsey Actually it doesn't matter if Von Neumann universe is a model of ZFC or not. What I'm really asking is that is the meaning of Von Neumann universe clear before we specify a model?

Comment: You should read the "Philosphical Perspectives" at the end of the Wikipedia link. In the definition of the $V_\beta$, $\cal P$ is the power set operator in the metatheory and so is taken as given, but what it means depends on your methodological stance.

Comment: I mean, we construct the von Neumann hierarchy *inside* the model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so yes, its meaning vary by choice of models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, what you are calling the von Neumann universe is nowadays more usually called the *cumulative hierarchy*. As von Neumann is also associated with another axiomatization of set theory (NBG), there is potential for confusion.

There is a formal definition of the power set in ZF, namely $y=P(x)$ means
$$\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow z\subseteq x)$$
or expanding out the defined relation $\subseteq$,
$$\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow \forall u (u\in z\to u\in x))$$
which as you can see is part of the axiom of power set you quoted. Using this defined relation, we can write the axiom:
$$\forall x\exists y(y=P(x))$$
Suppose $M$ is a model of ZF. If $x$ and $y$ are elements of $M$, then $M\models y=P(x)$ just means that $x$ and $y$ satisfy that formal definition in $M$.

I'm belaboring this point to answer this part of your question: "How can we say Von Neumann universe is model of ZFC as it uses a symbol that has not been defined?" $P(x)$ *has* been defined formally, so within the model $M$ we can construct the cumulative hierarchy *for that model*.

Now, models of ZF have an interesting feature: you can also look at them from "outside". This assumes the existence of some outer universe containing the model. Not to get too deeply into the philosophical weeds, let's just call this the "real" universe of sets, with the scare quotes.

Corresponding to $x\in M$ we have an "actual" set in the "real universe". It's the collection of all $y$'s of $M$ for which $M\models y\in x$. We can form the "actual" power set of this "actual" set. The "actual" power set may be bigger than the power set in $M$, as you've mentioned.

To pursue this inner vs. outer discussion further we'd need better notation; also we'd need to bring up other issues. But I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be badly mixing up the study of models of ZFC and the use of ZFC as a foundation for mathematics.  These are two totally separate things.  When you use ZFC as a foundation for mathematics, you assume the axioms of ZFC, and make definitions and prove theorems from those axioms.  Among the definitions you can make are the power set operation, and the von Neumann hierarchy, and so on.  You can also define things like the real numbers, and manifolds, and other mathematical structures of interest.  All of this is perfectly well-defined and does not involve any discussion of models at all.

One type of mathematical structure you can then define is a model of ZFC.  This is a set together with a binary relation such that it satisfies all the axioms of ZFC.  Within such a structure, you can then "internalize" definitions like the power set operation.  All that's going on in Skolem's paradox is that the power set operation you define in a specific model might not be the same as the true power set operation defined outside the model.  Different models can have different power sets of the same set, and in this sense the power set "depends on a choice of model".  But all of this is only talking about the internal power set operation of a model, not the external power set which you define when doing ordinary mathematics and aren't looking at a model.  The external power set has nothing to do with models and you can use it to do math as you normally would (and define things like the von Neumann hierarchy).

Comment: Do you mean that, to study oridinary mathematics, we actually don't need to discuss the model of ZFC and every sentence we use can be translated to an FOL sentence and what we do is merely doing induction using FOL, and things like Von Neumann universe is also (in essential) purely described by FOL sentences?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! But if that's correct, I have another question: people sometimes say FOL is too weak in some sense, but the language of set theory is stronger (like [this answer](https://qr.ae/py1QQf)). So what does that mean if sentences in the set theory are merely FOL sentences?

Comment: Take an example like group theory.  You could study group theory in first-order logic by writing down the axioms of a group as a first-order theory and then carrying out proofs based on that theory.  Or, you could define groups in the context of set theory (a group is a set with...) and study them with ZFC as your axioms.  The point being made is that studying groups in the context of set theory is more powerful (it can express and prove more things) than working just with the first-order theory of groups.